# Transforming data with a limited range (0,1,2) for parametric testing (ANOVA)

Tags: anova, data-transformation, nonparametric, range

I've collected data on accuracy of recognition of images. Accuracy is a score out of 2 with points 0,1,2.. participants can score a 0.

I am aiming to use a parametric test (ANOVA mixed design) to analyse data between groups.

I'm confronted with issues of normality with such a limited range. My query is; is there a way to transform the data into a workable range that would let me test for normality and hence use in a parametric test?

I'm aware of non-paramtrics, just wanted to check my parametric options...
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

There's no practical way to transform data that can only take three values that will be much use as far as achieving normality of the values goes. No matter what transformation you apply, it still takes three values.

On the other hand, most "standard" nonparametric procedures assume continuous distributions, which a variable that can only take three values really isn't ... so that alternative may not help as much as you'd like.

If your sample sizes are very large, normality may not be such a big issue, depending on exactly what analysis you're doing.